# Show that the mapping $I(f)(x) = \int_2^x f(t)dt$ is a linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Show that the mapping $I : C^0(\Bbb R) → C^1(\Bbb R)$ defined by $I(f)(x) =\int_2^x f(t)dt$ is a linear transformation.

Am I just proving that $I(v+w)= I(v)+C(w)$ and $I(cv)=cI(v)$?

And would that just involve replacing the x in the integral with $u$ and $v$?

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It includes effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Here $u$ and $v$ are elements of $C^0(\Bbb R)$, not $\Bbb R$.

Show that $$\int_2^x (cu)(t)dt=c\int_2^x u(t)dt$$ and $$\int_2^x (u+v)(t)dt=\int_2^x u(t)dt+\int_2^x v(t)dt.$$

Comment: So what do I use to show that the required properties hold?

Comment: I've edited the question, @user92399.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: You're welcome. You can thank me by upvoting and accepting the answer, @user92399.

Answer (score 0):

As you said,all you have to do is to prove that $I(f + g) = I(f) + I(g)$ and that $I(c*f) = c*I(f)$ for any real number c. 
For the first,notice that:  $I(f+g)$ = integral of $f+g$ = integral of $f$ + integral of ($g$)  (from 2 to $x$ )
For the second, $I(c*f)$ = integral of $c*f$ = c* integral of ($f$) 
Then the map given is linear.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Thanks,i ll try use it on my next answer.